# DATEDIFF on seconds

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

the bellow query gives me execution time in milliseconds

```
SELECT @StartTime=GETDATE() 
SELECT count(1) FROM tab1
SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in milliseconds]   
SELECT @TIMEVALUE = DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime)
```

the `ms` I guess for milliseconds , how to do convert to seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the count in second directly.

```
Select DATEDIFF(s, @Start, @End)
```

here more information on datediff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: I got this error 's' is not a recognized datediff option.
when runnig SELECT @TIMEVALUE = DATEDIFF(s,@StartTime,@EndTime)

Comment: milliseconds are 1000 seconds.... if the function does not support the format I guess you can divide. Try "second" instead that s... or "ss"

Comment: Got it. You can use second and ss

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:c2R5_ir-zP0J:infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X71771.htm&hl=it&gl=it&strip=1&vwsrc=0